# How do you enable S3 Object Logging to Cloud Trail using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudtrail

Its possible to do object logging on a S3 bucket to Cloud trail using the following guide, but this is through the console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this via the cli since want to do this for many buckets but haven't had much luck. I've setup a new cloud trail on my account and would like to map it to s3 buckets to do object logging. Is there a cli for this?

```
# This is to grant s3 log bucket access (no link to cloudtrail here)
aws s3api put-bucket-logging
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to use the CloudTrail [`put_event_selectors()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.put_event_selectors) command:

> **DataResources**
>
> CloudTrail supports data event logging for Amazon S3 objects and AWS Lambda functions.
>
> *(dict)*: The Amazon S3 buckets or AWS Lambda functions that you specify in your event selectors for your trail to log data events.

Do a search for `object-level` in the [documentation page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html).

Comment: Thanks, got this to work using the following... can update your answer if you want : aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name my_trail_name --event-selectors '[{"ReadWriteType": "All","DataResources": [{"Type": "AWS::S3::Object","Values": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME1/","arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME2/"]}],"IncludeManagementEvents": true}]'

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: The comment by `puji` in the accepted answer works. This is an expansion of that answer with the resources.

Here is the AWS documentation on how to do this through the AWS CLI

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/put-event-selectors.html

The specific CLI command you are interested is the following from the above documentation. The original documentation lists two objects in the same bucket. I have modified it to cover all the objects in two buckets.

```
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name TrailName --event-selectors '[{"ReadWriteType": "All","IncludeManagementEvents": true,"DataResources": [{"Type":"AWS::S3::Object", "Values": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket1/","arn:aws:s3:::mybucket2/"]}]}]'
```

If you want all the S3 buckets in your AWS accounts covered you can use `arn:aws:s3:::` instead of list of bucket arns like the following.

```
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name TrailName2 --event-selectors '[{"ReadWriteType": "All","IncludeManagementEvents": true,"DataResources": [{"Type":"AWS::S3::Object", "Values": ["arn:aws:s3:::"]}]}]'
```